# How to auto login ssh server and run some command to modify a file

Tags: c, linux

Here is the limitations:

1. No public key file uploaded to server (since this may be run at different target machine), this is just for an automatic testing program, so security is not a concern.
2. It's automatically program run background, so no user input.
3. I do not want to use "expect" which require user to install.
4. I have know the root user's password.

So I wonder is that a lightweight expect tool or a ssh library I can easily use to do such work.

Comment: Then, why using SSH? Why not writing on the server a program which does what you want and run it when the client telnets to port XXX?

Comment: This is an automation tool, the condition is that we know that the ssh service is started and we know the user/passwd. I want to know if there any lightweight expect like tool or how other product implement such auto login things without expect support, I think parse another process's input/ouput and do things like expect is a common requirement for many situations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

libssh http://www.libssh.org/ can help for a C project.
Using Perl, there is a module which can be used: Net::SSH (I use it for +/- the same kind of purposes)

Answer (score 0):

The only properly secure way is with an exported SSH public key file, where every client and every server have been verified - otherwise, what's to stop Mr. Havingabadday from exploiting the system?

Comment: security is not a problem we need to care at this situation.

Comment: To a lot of folks, security is never a concern - until something gets broken.